# Issue with Highcharts React Wrapper: Getting Highcharts error #18 but the same options passed to plain Highcharts Js is working fine

Tags: highcharts, react-highcharts

I am using "**Highcharts React Wrapper**" (https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts-react-official) with HighStocks and when using HighCharts wrapped in React Component as controlled component and updating the series or adding new series is giving below mentioned error:
**Highcharts error #18: www.highcharts.com/errors/18/**

> However, when the same chart options is copied and tried with plain JS
>   HighStocks example, then it works fine.

**Reproduced the issue in below link:**
https://codesandbox.io/s/highstock-react-wrapper-issue-hry5u

Comment: Another issue noticed was that same chart options when copy pasted in plain JS HighStocks sample in JSFiddle, the formatting is proper with series data coming up at expected height and position

Check the below sample of JSFIddle where-in the same chart option is copy pasted from the React example mentioned above and the chart comes up just fine

https://jsfiddle.net/ramprasads87/eb065qpr/2/

Comment: Would you like to achieve something like this https://codesandbox.io/s/highstock-react-wrapper-issue-i2b0o ?

Comment: @SebastianWędzel , yes, I would want to achieve something as you have illustrated in your link. I see that you have commented yAxis definition. This makes the chart distortion go away.

{
// unnecessary yAxis definition
    //yAxis: [],
    //
}

But in the same link that you have shared, if you click the button say 3 or 4 times, then you will be able to reproduce the reported issue.